# How can I spot positive recurrence?

Tags: stochastic-processes

Can someone please explain to me the intuition behind Positive recurrence. What does it mean and why is it different to normal recurrence?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the probability of return or recurrence is $1$ then the process or state is *recurrent*.

If the expected recurrence time is finite then this is called *positive-recurrent*; if the expected recurrence time is infinite then this is called *null-recurrent*.

See the [Wikipedia article on Markov chains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Recurrence) for more details.

*Added as an example:*

In a simple symmetric 1D random walk, the probability of first return after $2n$ steps is $\dfrac{\frac{1}{2n-1}{2n \choose n}}{2^{2n}}$.  Since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{\frac{1}{2n-1}{2n \choose n}}{2^{2n}} =1$, the probability of first return in finite time is $1$, so this is recurrent. But since  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2n \dfrac{\frac{1}{2n-1}{2n \choose n}}{2^{2n}}$ is infinite, the expected time of the first return is infinite, so this is null-recurrent.

Comment: Thanks, but I dont understand how the probability of return can be 1 but the expected recurrence time be infinity, surely then it will never return!

Comment: Rosie: the simple symmetric random walk on the integer line returns to its starting point after a random time which is finite with full probability and has infinite expectation. A random variable can very much be almost surely finite **and** not integrable.

Comment: @did are you saying that you can have a recurrent class so you will always return in a finite time but where the expected time taken to return can be infinite? I think I understand. So just to check, a state being recurrent means the probability of return in a finite time is 1, in addition to this now, every recurrent state is either positive recurrent or null recurrent. I have also got in my notes that if a state is null recurrent, then as n tends to infinity, the probability that we return to i in nd steps (where d is the period) is 0. Why is this? I cant understand.

Comment: @Rosie: The probability of (any, not necessarily first) return after $nd$ steps need not be $0$ for a null-recurrent state (it is not in the simple random walk) but it does need to tend towards $0$ as $n$ increases.

Comment: @Henry, yes sorry that is actually what I meant, but I cant think why, intuitively, it must tend to 0, what happens to make it that way?

Comment: @Rosie: If the probability of any return after $nd$ steps tended to some positive fraction $c$ then intuitively you will return roughly  a proportion $\frac{c}{d}$ of the time so the expected time between returns (i.e. for first return) is $\frac{d}{c}$.